# Trouble getting footer to vertical align middle

Tags: html, css

I'm using inline coding to code an eblast and my copy at the bottom in my footer will not vertically align middle to my social media images. Is there an issue in my code?

I have tried to include the `valign` in both the style and as a modifier. I also have `align` and `valign` in the code because I know without align this can throw off the code.

Thanks in advance.

Sample code:

```html
<tr>
    <td bgcolor="#dbe4e9" align="left" valign="middle" colspan="2" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 25px; padding-bottom: 15px; font-size: 11px; font-family: Century Gothic, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; color: #00447C; letter-spacing:0px">
    <hr style="height:1px;border:none;color:#00447C;background-color:#00447C;" />
    &copy; 2015 Project Lead The Way, Inc.
    <a href="https://www.pltw.org/privacy-policy" style="vertical-align:middle; font-size: 11px; font-family: Century Gothic, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; color: #00447C; letter-spacing:0px; text-decoration: none; border: none; padding:0 0 0 15">Privacy Policy</a>
    <a href="https://www.pltw.org/terms-service" style="vertical-align:middle; font-size: 11px; font-family: Century Gothic, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; color: #00447C; letter-spacing:0px; text-decoration: none; border: none; padding:0 15 0 15">Terms of Service</a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/projectleadtheway?sk=wall" style="text-decoration:none; border: none"><img alt="" src="Links/facebook_icon.gif" height="20px" width="20px" border="0" style="padding-left: 5px"/></a><a href="http://twitter.com/PLTWorg" style="text-decoration:none; border: none"><img alt="" src="Links/twitter_icon.gif" height="20px" width="20px" border="0" style="padding-left: 5px"/></a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/TeamPLTW" style="text-decoration:none; border: none"><img alt="" src="Links/youtube_icon.gif" height="20px" width="20px" border="0" style="padding-left: 5px"/></a><a href="https://instagram.com/pltworg/" style="text-decoration:none; border: none"><img alt="" src="Links/instagram_icon.gif" height="20px" width="20px" border="0" style="padding-left: 5px"/></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/project-lead-the-way" style="text-decoration:none; border: none"><img alt="" src="Links/linkedin_icon.gif" height="20px" width="20px" border="0" style="padding-left: 5px"/><hr style="height:1px;border:none;color:#00447C;background-color:#00447C;" /></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Try adding a height to the parent div and see if it can calculate the vertical height with that information. Also, try adding margin: auto 0; to the styling. Would you mind making a codepen or jsfiddle so we can figure this out for you easier?

Comment: Your top and bottom padding differ by 5px on the table cell.  Would that account for the issue?

Comment: Please first add the html and css code in seperate files, this hurt my eyes :s

Comment: Your links have a `padding-left` of `15`. Firstly, the unit is missing, so results will not be foreseeable. Add `px` or th unit of your choice to all non-0-values. Apart from that, what you want is `margin-left` since this will not unwantedly expand the clickable area of the link to its left.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far everyone. I fixed the padding by 5px on the bottom which has helped even that up. I have found that the issue is with my social media icons. If I set my <img align> to "top", it aligns the text on the bottom. If I align to "middle" it aligns the text to the top of the images

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are open to using tables.  If you are using tables, you can put the images in their own td's.  Each td will vertically align middle.  You may need to create a sub table for that.

There is a CSS way to use tables as well with display:table display:table-row display:table-cell .  The good thing about this is that you can make it responsive by changing display to block or whatever, when at different sizes.

Note: 
I see that you have an "hr" tag within an "a" anchor tag.  It doesn't look like it's affecting the display, but it's probably not something you intended.